# ASP.Net Identity 2 - Why doesn't my filter work?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, asp.net-mvc-filters

I've tried creating an easy filter to see if the user is in a role called "System Administrator", basically short hand for having to do `[Authorize(Roles = "System Administrator")]`. I thought it would be fairly simple, but I'm also fairly new to MVC so perhaps I'm overlooking something.

Here's my code:

```
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace site_redesign_web.Filters
{
    public class SystemAdminFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        string SysAdminRole = "System Administrator";

        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            if (filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.User != null)
            {
                var userSysAdmin = filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.User.IsInRole(SysAdminRole) == true;
                filterContext.ActionParameters["IsSysAdmin"] = userSysAdmin;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Can some one suggest where am I going wrong? A huge plus would be if the person isn't a System Administrator it would direct them to `Home/NoPermissions`.

Thank you!

Comment: can you expose the entire class of your filter?

Comment: Updated to show the entire class. Thank you!

Comment: this post might be useful to understand better https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/ASPNET-MVC-5-Security-And-44cbdb97

Comment: it will be easier if you inherit your custom filter from `AuthorizeAttribute`?

Comment: update your controller in which you want to implement this logic?

Comment: `(anything) == true` is redundant. You can eliminate the `== true` part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated: Fixing all issues.
AJ. Here you go... 
Finally fixed the problem

```
using ActionFilterAttribute 
using System.Web.Mvc;
namespace site_redesign_web.Filters
{
    public class SystemAdminFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        string SysAdminRole = "System Administrator";
        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            if (filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.User != null)
            {
                var userSysAdmin = filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.User.IsInRole(SysAdminRole) == true;

            if(!userSysAdmin)
            {
                filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(
                    new System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary{
                    {"controller", "Home"},     
                    {"action", "Index"}
                });
            }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and your **Controller** should be

```
[SystemAdminFilter]     // at controller level
public SomeController : Controller
{

}
```

or you can also use it for a particular **Action** by annotating like this

```
public SomeController : Controller
{
    [SystemAdminFilter]     // at Action level
    public ActionResult SomeAction()
    {
            // perform your actions
    }
```

It will work because I manually passed in the User with his role in the **Application_AuthorizeRequest** in Global.asax

```
protected void Application_AuthorizeRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     FormsAuthenticationTicket formsAuthenticationTicket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket("Aravind", true, 30);
     FormsIdentity formsIdentityId = new FormsIdentity(formsAuthenticationTicket);
     GenericPrincipal genericPrincipal = new GenericPrincipal(formsIdentityId, new string[] { "SystemUser" }); //TEST with this redirected to Home Index place
     HttpContext.Current.User = genericPrincipal ;
}
```

The next test I made was with this

```
GenericPrincipal genericPrincipal = new GenericPrincipal(formsIdentityId, new string[] { "System Administrator" }); //TEST with this did not perform an action
```

Comment: When I tried to implement this I got: HTTP Error 404.15 - Not Found
The request filtering module is configured to deny a request where the query string is too long. The URL ends up being over 2k long.

Comment: are your adding your filter in App_Start\FilterConfig in RegisterGlobalFilters method?

Comment: yep! Really don't know what's going on, it's very odd! Thank you!

Comment: are you in need with any help?

Comment: Yea, I don't know what my next steps should be. Now I'm wondering if it's really worth the hassle... Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: What is your complete requirement please share it here or invite for a discussion room also

Comment: I just want the SystemAdminFilter to work like [Authorize(Roles = "System Administrator")]. Just a short hand filter that could be implemented on both the controller level and action level.

Comment: Oops I have missed out **override** in OnAuthenticationChallenge method. Please add it and give an update.

Comment: Thank you for trying to help me out, however when I implement that override method it gives me: 'SystemAdminFilter.OnAuthenticationChallenge(AuthenticationChallengeContext)': no suitable method found to override

Comment: This works great for already logged in users, but if I'm not it still  passes in a User here: if (filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.User != null). I did make the changes to Global.asax and put in the Identity cookie name ".AspNet.ApplicationCookie" and for non logged in users it just continues to try to redirect them and eventually chome will stop and say theres a redirect loop. Thanks for you help on this!

Answer (score 1):

Since you are dealing with authorization, I would extend `AuthorizeAttribute` instead of `ActionFilterAttribute` which is mode general. You need to override only one method - `HandleUnauthorizedRequest` which is executed when authorization fails. Default implementation of AuthorizeAttribute already handles role based authorization for you.

```
public class SystemAdminAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    private const string SysAdminRole = "System Administrator";

    public SystemAdminFilter()
    {   
        //this defines the role that will be used to authorize the user:
        this.Roles = SysAdminRole;
    }  

    //if user is not authorized redirect to "Home/NoPermissions" page
    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        if(!filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext);
        }
        else
        {
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new
               RouteValueDictionary(new { controller = "Home", action = "NoPermissions" }));
         }
     }           
}
```

Once your attribute is implemented, decorate corresponding Controllers or Actions with it:

```
[SystemAdmin]
public SysAdminController : Controller
{
}
```

Comment: Looks good, but when I implemented it it throws anonymous users to the NoPermissions page. It only works when I'm logged in with System Administrator privileges.

Comment: It is very strange because when user is not authenticated (this condition is true: `!filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated`) the following line gets  executed: `base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext);` which should redirect to login page. Do you have something like that in your web.config?   '<error statusCode="401" redirect="~Home/NoPermissions" />'

Comment: Yep, as soon as I login without the System Administrator role, I get:The localhost page isn’t working

localhost redirected you too many times.

Comment: This is most probably because NoPermissions action or Home controller are decorated with SystemAdmin attribute - which causes inifinite loop of redirects...

Comment: I've only got the SystemAdmin filter on a couple of actions; none of which are implemented on the HomeController.